# Session Flash Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form that runs this controller code;

```
public function index()
{

    $date = date("Ymd");

    $temp_table = new TempTable;
    $generated_temp_table = $_POST['generated_temp_table'];
    $temp_table_data = $temp_table->setTempTable($generated_temp_table)->newQuery()->with('payment')->get();

    $payments = [];

    foreach($temp_table_data as $a_payment) {
        array_push($payments, $a_payment->payment->first()->attributesToArray());
    }

    //then create the Excel file
    Excel::create($date.'-SME_Payments_Export-U', function($excel) use ($payments) {

        $excel->sheet('Excel sheet', function($sheet) use ($payments) {
            $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');
            $sheet->fromArray($payments);
        });
    })->export('csv');

    \Session::flash('flash_message', 'Your CSV is downloading');

    Redirect::back();

}
```

The `flash` message isn't being shown. Here is the view code;

```
@if(Session::has('flash_message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success {{Session::has('flast_message_important') ? 'alert-important' : ''}}">
        @if(Session::has('flash_message_important'))
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        @endif
        {{ session('flash_message')}}
    </div>
@endif
```

I have included the `use Session;` at the top of both controllers. Here it is in the config/app.php;

```
'Session'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session',
```

Is there more to it than what I am trying here?

Comment: Do you make any ajax request during the loading of the page ? If so, the Session::flash make data available only for the current and next request (only!). If you  make a Session::flash(), the message is still available, but if an Ajax request is done during the page loading. The data is not avaible, because the ajax request consumed the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using [Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs).

Anything below `Excel::create()->export();` is never executed.

The export method uses the current connection to transfer the file to the user. Any output after the download would be written into that file. So the **export method** calls the `exit;` function to prevent any additional output and to ensure a valid file. (Any details are in the [source code](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/2.0/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/Writers/LaravelExcelWriter.php))

So one possible "solution" would be to move `Session::flash();` up. But this wouldn't solve your problem of showing the user a flash message.

Assuming you have a page with a *Download Report* button which leads to this controller method. The users clicks on it and and the download starts. But the current page is not reloaded, the flash message dosen't show up. Only if the users goes to a different page the flash message will be displayed.

To avoid this use some JavaScript to force a reload of the current page or make the JavaScript show the flash message for you when pressing the download button.